# Self signed SSL certificate with a wild card - works for sub domain, fails for the main domain

Tags: subdomain, https, security-certificate, certificate-generation

For development purposes I created a self signed SSL certificate where CN = `*.example.com`.

After installing the certificate, when browsing to any sub domain `https://sub.example.com` I got the nice green lock indicating that everything is OK, but when browsing to `https://example.com` I still keep getting an error. The browser says: "Server's certificate does not match the URL"

How can I resolve this issue so I will have 1 certificate that is valid for both all sub-domains and the main domain.

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to create quickly a self signed certificate with "Subject Alternative Names" so I just made another one for "example.com".

Comment: Are you sure that `example.com` is pointing to the correct server that has your certificate? If you are using Google's naked domain redirect for example, it will show the message you describe.

Comment: Which tool do you use to generate your self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name verification is guided by [RFC 2818 Section 3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1), more specifically on wildcards:

> ```
>    Matching is performed using the matching rules specified by
>    [RFC2459].  If more than one identity of a given type is present in
>    the certificate (e.g., more than one dNSName name, a match in any one
>    of the set is considered acceptable.) Names may contain the wildcard
>    character * which is considered to match any single domain name
>    component or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com matches foo.a.com but
>    not bar.foo.a.com. f*.com matches foo.com but not bar.com.
> ```

Here the "domain name components" a separated by the dots, and do not include them.

This is also clarified in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) (which also discourages the use of wildcard certificates, but that's a different problem).

Instead of putting your host name in the Common Name RDN of the Subject DN, you could have two Subject Alternative Name entries in the same certificate: one for `*.example.com` and one for `example.com`. The CN is only meant to be a [fallback solution anyway](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1):

> ```
>    If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that MUST
>    be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common Name
>    field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used. Although
>    the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is deprecated and
>    Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the dNSName instead.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on `https://www.example.com`? If so you may need to create another certificate for your main domain.

Comment: Adding a second certificate is a solution, but I want to use 1 certificate. Is this even possible?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just emailed GoDaddy asking them. I also have to buy a wild card SSL soon and wondering if i'll need two or them now my self. Did you test it using `www` in your domain name which is technically a sub-domain? I know that regular SSL's from GoDaddy cover both your `www` and `non-www` versions of your domain name. I don't know if that's just a feature GoDaddy offers or part of SSL in general.

Comment: I think I am missing a field called "Subject Alternative Names". Trying to create a new certificate with this field, will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Godaddy just replied "The Wild Card SSL will protect the the domain itself as well as all subdomains.  It protects the whole domain name."

Comment: Were you able to secure your entire domain?